# mapping dynamic xml nodes to static nodes

Tags: xslt

I am looking for someone to assist in solving a seemingly simple problem.
I want to map a node of  /fields[x]/message_id to a static node /MessageID0x for 5 entries in a list.
The source node is optional and may not exist.
The schema is below
I am just not seeing the obvious, I hope.

The source is defined as:

```
<xs:element name="fields">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="tenant_id" type="xs:normalizedString" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="message_id" type="xs:normalizedString" minOccurs="0"/>
```

Target is defined as:

```
<xs:element name="MessageID01" type="xs:normalizedString" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="MessageID02" type="xs:normalizedString" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="MessageID03" type="xs:normalizedString" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="MessageID04" type="xs:normalizedString" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="MessageID05" type="xs:normalizedString" minOccurs="0"/>
```

=== FROM ===========

```
<root>
<ID>2019Nov12_17</ID>
<PingResult>OK</PingResult>
<StartDateTime>2019-11-12T16:16:01</StartDateTime>
<EndDateTime>2019-11-12T17:16:01.771Z</EndDateTime>
<start>0</start>
<numFound>1</numFound>
<fields>
    <tenant_id>KOCHIND_AX2</tenant_id>
    <message_id>lid://infor.landmark.lmrkmt/15d8f834-7680-541e-0000-001d5dae3e7b</message_id>
</fields>
<fields>
    <tenant_id>KOCHIND_AX2</tenant_id>
    <message_id>lid://infor.landmark.lmrkmt/0535a86a-7680-1868-0000-07625db833c1</message_id>
</fields>
<fields>
    <tenant_id>KOCHIND_AX2</tenant_id>
    <message_id>lid://infor.landmark.lmrkmt/0535a86a-7680-1864-0000-03445db849c8</message_id>
</fields>
<fields>    
    <tenant_id>KOCHIND_AX2</tenant_id>
    <message_id>lid://infor.landmark.lmrkmt/0535a86a-7680-1867-0000-01151db125c8</message_id>
</fields>
</root>
```

TO ===================

```
<root>
<ID>2019Nov12_17</ID>
<PingResult>OK</PingResult>
<StartDateTime>2019-11-12T16:16:01</StartDateTime>
<EndDateTime>2019-11-12T17:16:01.771Z</EndDateTime>
<start>0</start>
<numFound>1</numFound>
<MessageID01>lid://infor.landmark.lmrkmt/15d8f834-7680-541e-0000-001d5dae3e7b</MessageID01>
<MessageID02>lid://infor.landmark.lmrkmt/0535a86a-7680-1868-0000-07625db833c1</MessageID02>
<MessageID03>lid://infor.landmark.lmrkmt/0535a86a-7680-1868-0000-07625db833c8</MessageID03>
<MessageID04>lid://infor.landmark.lmrkmt/15d8f834-1864—3322-0000-03445db125c8</MessageID04>
<MessageID05>lid://infor.landmark.lmrkmt/15d8f834-7680-1867-0000-01151db125g4</MessageID05>
</root>
```

Comment: So in your sample output there shouldn't be a `<MessageID05>` element, right?

Comment: Are you really sure you have to go this route? Doing something like is is generally considered bad practice because it means changing the schema just for adding another element in the future.

Comment: Hi Filburt, maximun can be 5 but it is optional which means can be 0 to 5

Comment: I fully understand your scenario but your output result cannot include `<MessageID05>` if only 4 input `<field>`elements are provided. What is your specific reason to define `<xs:element name="MessageID01" type="xs:normalizedString" minOccurs="0"/>` when you simply could do `<xs:element name="MessageID" type="xs:normalizedString" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="5" />` and transform `fields/message_id` to `MessageID`? Every time I've seen done what you are doing it was because the output consumer did parse the Xml as text instead of processing Xml.

Comment: ok, suppose i can modify my xsd according to your suggetion, how can i achive the result?

Comment: Please clarify the logic of the given example. The input has 4 `message_id` nodes, the output has 5 `MessageIDxx` nodes - and the Id values do not match.

Comment: sorry michael, message_id are 5, i missed one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the requested result can be achieved rather simply by doing:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="fields">
    <xsl:variable name="n">
        <xsl:number format="01"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:element name="MessageID{$n}">
        <xsl:value-of select="message_id"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result of transforming the example input will be:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<root>
  <ID>2019Nov12_17</ID>
  <PingResult>OK</PingResult>
  <StartDateTime>2019-11-12T16:16:01</StartDateTime>
  <EndDateTime>2019-11-12T17:16:01.771Z</EndDateTime>
  <start>0</start>
  <numFound>1</numFound>
  <MessageID01>lid://infor.landmark.lmrkmt/15d8f834-7680-541e-0000-001d5dae3e7b</MessageID01>
  <MessageID02>lid://infor.landmark.lmrkmt/0535a86a-7680-1868-0000-07625db833c1</MessageID02>
  <MessageID03>lid://infor.landmark.lmrkmt/0535a86a-7680-1864-0000-03445db849c8</MessageID03>
  <MessageID04>lid://infor.landmark.lmrkmt/0535a86a-7680-1867-0000-01151db125c8</MessageID04>
</root>
```

which is different from the result you show - nevertheless, I suspect it is the correct one.

---

Do note that numbering sibling nodes by name is bad practice. It makes subsequent transformations much more difficult. If you need a number (although I don't see why you should), use an attribute.